# change DNS server in a non-persistent way (on the command-line) [rescue mode]

Tags: 16.04, networking, 18.04, dns, rescue-mode

is there a way i can change the DNS server on the command-line without having to change anything on the disk?

i recently booted into the rescue session and i got an IP address (using DHCP) but no DNS server. as my network config is usually done with the `nm-applet` in the desktop session and not in `/etc/network/interfaces` i would like to be able to provide a DNS server just for this rescue session and not write anything on disk.

this is usually possible by editing `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf`. but `resolvconf` seems not to be running in the ubuntu 14.04 rescue session.

i was hoping there was something similar to the network configuration where i can configure an interface without having to edit a file:

```
# ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.5 netmask 255.255.255.0
# route add default gw 192.168.2.1
```

is there a way to do this for DNS in a rescue session on ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: Do you try to simple add `dns` server in `nm-applet` for connection?

Comment: i am in the rescue session - command line only - there is no `nm-applet`.

Comment: Then try to write dns to `/etc/resolv.conf`. Edit `/etc/resolv.conf` and add `nameserver ip_address_of_dns`

Comment: that is the best workaround i could come up with so far - but it changes the configuration on the disk...

Comment: You must to change something if you wont dns to work :)

Comment: nope. found a way!

Comment: Great, I must remember. Up vote from me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

i found a way to do this:

kill the dns service (there may be a more subtle way?)

```
# killall dnsmasq
```

restart the service using the desired upstream server:

```
# dnsmasq --server=192.168.2.1
```

---

on a newer ubuntu (one with `systemd`) this would be:

```
# systemd-resolve -i enp0s31f6 --set-dns=192.168.2.1  # --set-dnssec=true
```

check with:

```
# systemd-resolve --status
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to this directory `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d`
edit the head file using vi or vim with su privilege

```
sudo vi /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

add the following lines to the file

```
nameserver *DNS server IP*
```

save the file and use resolvconf utility to set the static DNS server address you entered by the following command

```
sudo resolvconf -u
```

Comment: thanks. but this requires writing on the disk. and in the rescue session `resolvconf` complains: `Error: /run/resolvconf/interface either does not exist or is not a directory`. removing the link `/etc/resolv.conf` and then writing directly into a file of that name seems simpler.

Comment: Moreover, that file stands clearly with a "`# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN`".

Answer (score 0):

To get this to work, I added `au.archive.ubuntu.com` to the `/etc/hosts` file with an IP address I got from pinging it on my PC.

Then did `apt update` and it resolved.

Comment: this will then only resolve that particular domain. any other DNS request will remain unresolved. but i agree, `apt` will work in the rescue session (but nothing else that needs DNS).